# Google VR + Unity = tracking stuttering / jittering / choppy

Tags: android, performance, unity-game-engine, google-vr, google-vr-sdk

Launching `GVRDemo` scene using Unity5.4.2f2-GVR13 installation package I'm experiencing unsteady tracking on my Samsung Galaxy S7. As you can see on an attached video it's not caused by low frame rate nor any of my code since the only thing I've changed in the scene is switching the `cubeRoom` object with a textured sphere object which better visualises the issue:

https://youtu.be/_NRQNbtdpuI

- It doesn't matter if I change the quality setting from `Fantastic` to `Fastest`.
- As you can see the frame rate doesn't drop around the stuttering moments, so it's not about the CPU/GPU performance

As I test the *Google Street View* app for example, there's no such issue – is it because it's been written natively for Android?
On the other hand I've noticed games like *VR Fantasy* with tracking system  behaving differently – more smoothly due to the delay in the reaction time regarding the device's movement (looks nice, but causes nausea after 5 seconds). This makes me believe there is an issue with Google VR tracking.

Is anyone experiencing the same thing? What might be the reason for it?

Answer (score 0):

I am also testing a simple VR app made with Unity (5.6b9), and i'm finding that Android performance is rather poor.  This is the case on cheap phones (Moto G, $150) as well as fancy phones (Nexus 5X, Asus ZenFone 3) and even expensive phones (Samsung S6).

I'm particularly puzzled by how poor the performance of a VERY simple VR app made with unity is (empty scene, a cube and a sphere, no special lighting, single pass rendering...).  The Samsung S6 performes very well with native GearVR apps, or photos/videos.  All the phones perform very well with things like street view or youtube.

The same unity app running on iOS outperformer all the androids by a wide margin.

Are there some tricks we're not aware of for getting performance out of android?

Comment: Interesting observations regarding different devices – thanks for sharing. I've just tested the same app on Samsung S7 Edge and it works flawlessly.

Answer (score -1):

I'm using Unity5.4.2f2-GVR13 too, and I think it's just random.

Charging up your phone and controller, and rebooting the phone seems to help a lot.